# Расшифровать слово с ключом на Java

Tags: java

Пытаюсь написать код на Java,который с помощью ключа и методом перестановки расшифрует слово,Посоветуйте как можно это реализовать?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String word="РОИАГДВН";
      int key[]={6,4,2,7,5,8,1,3};
      Arrays.sort(key);

  }
} 

/// Здесь  код должен преобразовать 
зашифрофанное слово РОИАГДВН в слова ВИНОГРАД используя ключ
```

Comment: Ну например сделать массив char. сделать цикл по `key`. дальше из строки берем символ по индексу `i` цикла и такой же из массива `key`. Вставляем в массив `char` по индексу `key[i]` символ `word[i]` и всё. Дальше массив в строку и готово

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не совсем, там в ключе первый элемент - это единица, а не ноль, выйдет за массив

Comment: @DmitriyD в языках уже путаюсь) в каком-то есть индексация с 1, к моему удивлению))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String word = "РОИАГДВН";
int[] key = { 6, 4, 2, 7, 5, 8, 1, 3 };
char[] result = new char[key.length];
for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    result[key[i] - 1] = word.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```